# Why did Sang-woo use Clause 3 of the games but vote to continue?

Tags: plot-explanation, squid-game

Spoiler in this question for Squid Game.  In the first episode of Squid Game,

> Sang-woo enacts clause 3 of the games; that if there are a majority of people who vote to stop, they would stop the game.  However, when they showed how everyone voted, he voted to continue.  Why is this?

My guess is he initially was shocked from

> the people who were killed and wanted to stop because he didn't want to die.

But when he saw the money in the plastic piggybank, he changed his mind?  Is this the reason why he said what he said to the game master but voted opposite what he said to the game master?

Comment: If you've not seen all of it yet, be aware that answers to this may well contain spoilers for the rest of the series.